# Javascript: When press the CANCEL button still saving the data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my problem for almost a week and I can't resolve it.

Scenario:

Before I save a data an confirmation message will appear saying that... `Station is full. do you want to continue saving?`... then when I tried to CANCEL it, its still saving the data..

Pressing the CANCEL button it will not save anymore....

Assuming that I have a Building Name : Star 1, and Star 2...

the **"Star 1"**, and **"Star 2"** will be the value of **$bldg**..then the total duration for *STAR 1 is 08:00:00 [this is already full]*, then for *STAR 2 is 00:00:00 [not exist yet in database]*

Here's my code:

```
if (isset($_GET['js_varOK'])) 
$cancel = $_GET['js_varOK'];
else $cancel = "not";

    if($cancel != "yes")
    {
        for($i=0; $i<sizeof($bldg);$i++)
        {
        if($cancel != "yes")
        {   
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbldata WHERE  fldNetname = '".$network."' AND fldBldgName = '".$bldg[$i]."'  AND  fldWeek = '".$week."' AND fldMonth = '".$month."'  AND fldYear ='".$year."' ORDER BY id desc");
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
        {
        $totalduration = "";
        $seconds = 0;
        $minutes = 0;

        $computeSecMin = $seconds * $minutes; 
        $subSecMin = $computeSecMin + $duration; 
        $getMin = floor($subSecMin/60); 
        $getSec = $subSecMin%60; 
        $totalduration = $getMin .":". $getSec; 
        $query2 = "INSERT INTO tbldata(fldNetname,fldBldgName,fldPlaylist,fldMonth,fldWeek,fldYear,fldDuration,fldFrom,fldTo,fldTotalDuration,fldTimestamp,fldStatus, fldUser) VALUES ('".$network."','".$bldg[$i]."','".$AdName."','".$month."','".$week."','".$year."','".$duration."','".$from."','".$to."', '".$totalduration."','".$date."','".$status."',(SELECT fldid from tblmembers where fldUsername= '".$_SESSION['user']."'))";
        mysql_query($query2) or die (mysql_error());    

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
        echo "alert('Data have been saved first!');\n";
        echo "</script>";       
        }
        else
        {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
        if($network == "Mass and Mobile" && $row[fldTotalDuration]  == "08:00:00"  && $duration >= "0 s")
        {?><?php
        if(sizeof($bldg) == 1)
        {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
        echo "alert('$bldg[$i] station is already full.');\n";
        echo "window.location='booking_content.php'";
        echo "</script>";
        }
        else
        { ?>
        <script>
        var myVar = "station is already full. Do you want to save the other networks?";
        var js_varOK;
        var bldg;
        var network;
        if (confirm(myVar)) 
        {
        js_varOK = "no";
        bldg = "<?php echo $bldg?>";
        network= "<?php echo $network?>";
        window.location = "?js_varOK=" + js_varOK + "&bldg="+bldg + "&network="+network;
        } else 
        {
        js_varOK = "yes";
        window.location = "?js_varOK=" + js_varOK;

        }
        </script>
        <?php
        }

        }
        }

    }
    else
    {
       //do noothing
    }
```

So when I hit the CANCEL it will just go to `else of do nothing`...BUT its still saving..

Based on my understanding...the STAR 1 will be the first to read the program for the for loop and after that it will go to `"if($network == "Mass and Mobile" && $row[fldTotalDuration]  == "08:00:00"  && $duration >= "0 s")"` then a pop up message will appear then I will click the cancel button then the value of `$cancel` is already "yes" then the STAR 2 is already saved in my database  which is it should be stop the program to save it when cancel clicked....

thanks..

Comment: Where is the value of $cancel coming from? In the first line, you check to see if it is "yes", but you don't show how/where it gets set.

Comment: @echosa..sorry i forgot to include that...I edit my post...

Comment: Do an evaluation of the $_GET in your first if statment. I usually do a alert(); You're also not using {}. So clean up the if, and do an alert on what isset() is returning. I would match it to a value vs. just the presence of the key.

Comment: If the saving is still happening, then it seems that js_varOK is getting set to "yes". Do what Anna said, and also look at the code where js_varOK is getting set and passed as a GET param (either as a form element or a manual value). I suspect that the issue is occurring even before the code you have shown us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `$_GET['js_varOK']` **is set in both cases**. It's just empty, if you don't want to save.

Try to proof like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['js_varOK']) && $_GET['js_varOK'] != '') { // better way: .. && $_GET['js_varOK'] == 'yes'
    echo 'save';
} else {
    echo 'dont save';
}
```

I recommend to clean up your code a little. Use

```
if ($a == $b) {
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    echo 'no';
}
```

instead of

```
if ($a == $b) echo 'yes';
else echo 'no';
```

It's just a little bit more code but not that error-prone.